# Pandas sum rows by group based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have weekly data grouped by region. I'm trying to figure out how to sum a set of rows based on a condition for each region. For example:

```
Region  | Week | Year | value
------------------------------
  R1    |   53 | 2016 | 10
  R1    |    1 | 2017 | 8
  R2    |   53 | 2017 | 10
  R2    |    1 | 2018 | 17
  R3    |   53 | 2018 | 30
  R3    |    1 | 2019 | 1
```

I would like add every value of week 53 from the previous year to the first week of the following year to turn it into:

```
Region  | Week | Year | value
------------------------------
  R1    |    1 | 2017 | 18
  R2    |    1 | 2018 | 27
  R3    |    1 | 2019 | 31
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`agg` can be very useful here. Try this:

```
df = df.groupby('Region', as_index=False).agg({'Year':'max', 'value':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Region  Year  value
0     R1  2017     18
1     R2  2018     27
2     R3  2019     31
```

Answer (score 1):

Format Year and week of the year to be able to convert into date.

Extract the time components and proceed to groupby and sum

```
 s=pd.to_datetime(df.Year * 1000 + df.Week * 10 + 0, format='%Y%W%w')
df=(df.assign(Year=np.where(df['Week']==53,s.dt.year, df['Year']),
             Week=np.where(df['Week']==53,s.dt.isocalendar().week, df['Week']))
        .groupby(['Region', 'Year', 'Week']).agg('sum'))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without turning week and year to date? I'm working with epidemiological calendars of 52 weeks so I need to do the summation before converting the date. Thank you.

Comment: You will effectively be grouping by Region if that's the case, @richardec answer should suffice then